# Special characters not working with custom font

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, fonts, special-characters

I'm having trouble with special characters (like â é ü) when using a custom font in my app.

For some reason, it's replacing the accented characters with seemingly random characters. I'm trying to set a `UILabel`'s text to the word **Château** but both this:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Château"];
```

and (

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ch\u00E1teau"];
```

are setting the label text to **Ch,teau**. This is only happening when using the custom font, when I log the result in the console the correct character shows up. I've tried setting a different string encoding. These characters so exist within the font (if i type the same word in TextEdit, MS Word, etc it shows up fine), I've also validated and inspected the font in FontBook. It's an .OTF font.

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: what is the font family of the custom font? by the way: your special char's unicode is `U+00E2`.

Comment: The font is 'Agenda Medium':  http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/agenda/medium/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all font sets have all characters. Open the charactermap in windows load your custom font and see if it exists. It could be that the author of the font has in advertantly placed it at the wrong code. [image: See the differences in these two fonts]

Comment: as suggested in my original message, I've already checked this in FontBook (mac equiv.) and the characters do exist. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Your right, sorry. I did not pay attention to the tags. Not knowing what Fontbook was should have veered me in the Apple direction. Should we delete the answer as its clearly noise in the thread?

Comment: The font was indeed incorrectly mapped for certain characters. Going to find an alternative font... Thanks @Joe

Comment: how was it incorrectly mapped if it worked in Word and other programs? Can you please elaborate, I am having the same issue here!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ch\u00E1teau"]
```

Note the forward slash was changed to a backslash.

PS: verified in real program.

Comment: whoops, i typed it incorrectly in my message above, but i was using the correct slash in the program. good spot

Comment: Post your font to dropbox where people can look at it.